# Change text color with useState in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

I have a class `color.js` in which I've defined some color codes which is stuctured as:

```
export default {
  black: '#000',
  white: '#fff',
  yellow: '#C18D00',
  green: '#1AE06A'
}
```

In a component that I made `BookedCard.js` I've many statuses of the booking like confirmed, pending, etc. Based on each status I want to change the color of the text for example:

```
function BookedCard({ status, title, dateTime }) {

    const [ statusColor, setStatusColor ] = useState(color.black)

    switch (status) {
        case 'Pending':
            setStatusColor(color.yellow)
            break;
        case 'Rejected':
            setStatusColor(color.red)
            break;
        case 'Confirmed':
            setStatusColor(color.green)
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Then I'm using it in the component as:

```
<Text style={[styles.status, { color: statusColor }]}>{status}</Text>
```

It shows the error:

> Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Now, I understand by reading other questions about what's happening here, the `useState` is stuck in the loop of rendering the component again and again but I can't seem to figure out how it can be solved in my case may be the answer is there but I'm too new to uderstand it at the moment.

Comment: Hard to see how your components are interacting to give a proper solution, but the way `BookedCard` is currently written will certainly catch it in an endless loop of renders. You can put the switch inside a `useEffect`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two ways to solved it:

1. use a `useEffect` hook.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    switch (status) {
        // ...
    }
}, [status])
```

2. before you calling a setState, such as `setStatusColor(color.yellow)`, you need to check that if the color is already `yellow` or not. for example:

```
if (statusColor !== color.yellow) {
  setStatusColor(color.yellow)
}
```

These may help you outof the  infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly set state inside functional component. Ideally it should be like this:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

function BookedCard({ status, title, dateTime }) {
  const [statusColor, setStatusColor] = useState(color.black);

  useEffect(() => {
    switch (status) {
      case "Pending":
        setStatusColor(color.yellow);
        break;
      case "Rejected":
        setStatusColor(color.red);
        break;
      case "Confirmed":
        setStatusColor(color.green);
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }, [status]);
}
```